# Vue reactivness for dynamically created components

Tags: typescript, vue.js

We've built a wysiwig editor with VueJS using TypeScript and [vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator). I can't really go into detail and extracting a code snipped to show the issue is nearly impossible. Thus I hope I can explain the issue enough and maybe someone can give some pointers, where we may have a bug.

The root component is the Layout Editor which has a layout panel and a properties panel, similar to fat clients. You can arrange elements in this layout panel with a [drag&drop component](https://github.com/mauricius/vue-draggable-resizable).
The component hierarchy is like this:
LayoutEditor -> BaseElement (which contains the drag&drop component) -> Actual Element (which is in the slot of the drag&drop component).
Some simplified code examples:

```
<layout-editor>
    <base-element v-for="(element) in elements" :element="element" :key="element.id"></base-element>
</layout-editor>
```

BaseElement:

```
<vue-draggable-resizable>
    <component
        :is="element.componentType"
        :data="element.componentData"
</vue-draggable-resizable>
```

**The problem**

A new element is added to the layout editor, by pushing it into the `elements` array and saving the properties. The component is then rendered correctly according its properties, but any further changes to the properties are not reflected in the layout panel.
The data is stored in a mongodb, so when the whole page is refreshed and the layout editor mounted with all its child elements, the properties can be changed as much as you want and the changes are reflected immediatly. Only newly added ones behave differently and we can't see what is different if the `elements` array is loaded through axios or if we push an element into, once it is loaded. It would be easier to understand if new elements wouldn't be rendered properly, but the first save to the properties works, only subsequent ones don't.

Any ideas what could be our mistake when adding new elements?

Comment: you can force an component to update by changing its key like this `<someComponent :key="someKey"></someComponent>`. everytime you want to re-update the component you simply change the value of `someKey`. like: `++someKey` if its a number. this could be a temporary solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you describe it could be a problem of complex objects nesting, known to have problems with reactivity

> Sometimes you may want to assign a number of properties to an existing
> object, for example using Object.assign() or _.extend(). However, new
> properties added to the object will not trigger changes. In such
> cases, create a fresh object with properties from both the original
> object and the mixin object.

Now, I see that when the properties are taken from the DB you do not have this problem, so it can lead to look on how you add the properties to the newly created element; because when you pull down from the DB all the properties are more likely already instanced by your backend code.

As example of what I'm saying, lets take a User.

If I pull a user from the db, in the very easy case it has an ID, an email and a psw.

But if I create the user in frontend (eg in a register form), I won't have the id, until I add it to the user in case of successful creation. Depending on how I defined my user in the store, and how I add the new properties, those will, or not, be reactive.

Usually using the Vue API method `Vue.set(obj,prop,value)` or creating a new Object from the stored one solve this problem.

```
this.modifiedElement = {
    ...this.modifiedElement,
    foo: 'fresh-foo',
    bar: 'fresh-bar',
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sounds like this could be the case. Though I am a bit confused with the last statement. Usually if you replace an object you lose its reactivity, no?

Comment: Good thing we have one component handling the properties, so replacing the assigning of properties with Vue.set() seems to have done the trick!

Comment: Great! I was out, just seen the other message. Well, rectrating the object force vue to update, I think that's the reason.